# takeWhile in Scala for element n+1

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

- Define the function dropWhileSmallerThanFive, it should take a list and discard the first n elements, until the next element (n+1) is greater or equal to 5.

  *Use one of Scala's built-in list functions (e.g. takeWhile).

I tried this:

```
   def dropWhileSmallerThanFive(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case head :: b :: tail if b >= 5 => head :: (b::tail).takeWhile(_>=5)
        case _ => Nil 
    }
```

But it's completly wrong, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! If you are new to Scala, consider the following beginner-friendly resources

- Real-time help: [gitter.im/scala/scala](https://gitter.im/scala/scala)
- Interactive exercises: [scala-exercises.org](https://www.scala-exercises.org)
- Tour of Scala: [docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html)
- Hello world template: `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8`
- Online interactive playground: [scastie.scala-lang.org](https://scastie.scala-lang.org)

---

Scala provides [`List.dropWhile`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#dropWhile(p:A=%3EBoolean):C) out-of-the-box, or consider the following recursive implementation

```
def recDropWhile(l: List[Int], predicate: Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: List[Int], predicate: Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
    l match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case head :: tail => if (predicate(head)) loop(tail, predicate) else (head :: tail)
    }
  }
  loop(l, predicate)
}
```

Both output

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
l.dropWhile(_ < 5)       // res3: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 8)
recDropWhile(l, _ < 5)   // res4: List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 8)
```